# jQuery multiple get id from different <select>

Tags: jquery, attributes, html-select, multiple-select

I am quite new to jQuery and got a problem with finding the right select on the page.
When I search for multiple select I get how to select a few options and its not what I need.

So basicly here is an example:

**Html part:**

```
<div id='select-zone'>
   <select class='nselect' id='1'>
       <option value='1'>test</option>
       <option value='2'>test2</option>
   </select>

   <select class='nselect' id='2'>
       <option value='1'>test</option>
       <option value='2'>test2</option>      
   </select>
</div>
```

So basically I want to get the id from the select using the class attribute 'nselect'.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var id;
$("nselect").change(function() 
   id = $(this).attr('id');
});
});
```

I think that my problem is that I am not getting the right element with this.
If you guys could guide me and tell me what I am doing wrong and if I am even accessing the right element with $(this) you would be a great life saver.

I made a code simplest possible.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `.` off your [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), and the opening curly brace off the callback function:

```
$(".nselect").change(function() {
// ^ missed this                ^ and this

   id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

---

Side note: you could make your code a bit more efficient by just using the native `id` property, rather than creating a new jQuery object:

```
$(".nselect").change(function() {
   id = this.id;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't sure if it was good but seams to have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, as `nselect` is a class name, you'll need to use `$(".nselect")` rather than just `$('nselect')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a dot to address classes

```
$(".nselect")
```

Also, I would use .blur() instead of .change()

Comment: Thansk I will try the blur and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to use the id variable, I believe you'd want to put `var id;` before the `$(document).ready...`

Comment: Basicly I am aiming to get the id and use it in an ajax function to update my database so I need to get the id in the function.